# How to mock methods that is called from Azure Function?

Tags: c#, moq

The problem of Azure Functions is that their Run function must be static. This Run function calls a function that performs a database search query. I would love to mock this function

```
namespace Something.App{
    public class Something {        
        [FunctionName("Something")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {   
            //perform something
            dbCall(); // I wish to mock
            //perform something
            return new OkObjectResult(result); 
        }
```

However, mocking attempts at this has failed. The test itself ran, but it doesn't run the mocked version, it just run the original version which uses internet connection.

```
namespace Something.Test{
    public class SomethingTest{
        private readonly ILogger logger = TestFactory.CreateLogger();

        private Mock<Something> CreateMockObject(){

            var mock = new Mock<Something>();

            mock.SetupSequence(f => f.dbCall()).Returns(something);
            return mock;
        }

        [Fact]

        public async void Http_Respond_On_Valid_Data()
        {
            CreateMockObject();
            Dictionary<string,StringValues> postParam= new Dictionary<string,StringValues>();
            postParam.Add("param", "value");

            var request = new DefaultHttpRequest(new DefaultHttpContext()){
                Query = new QueryCollection(postParam)
            };

            var response = (OkObjectResult)await Something.Run(request, logger);
            string stringResponse = (String) response.Value;
            Assert.Equal("XKCD", stringResponse);
        }
```

I have tried to separate the method into a non static class (let's say SomethingTool) and achieve something like this.

```
namespace Something.App{
    public class Something {        
        [FunctionName("Something")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {   
            SomethingTool object = new SomethingTool();
            //perform something
            object.dbCall(); // I wish to mock
            //perform something
            return new OkObjectResult(result); 
        }
```

But it didn't quite do the job. For this project, using Moq is a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to refactor the function  to abstract out the dependencies so that they can be replaced as needed when testing

For example

```
public static class Something {

    public static Func<ISomeDependency> Factory = () => return new SomeDependency();

    [FunctionName("Something")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log) { 

        //...

        ISomeDependency tool = Factory.Invoke();
        var result = await tool.dbCall();

        //...

        return new OkObjectResult(result); 
    }
}
```

Which can now be tested like

```
public class SomethingTest{
    private readonly ILogger logger = TestFactory.CreateLogger();

    [Fact]
    public async Task Http_Respond_On_Valid_Data() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = "XKCD";
        var mock = new Mock<ISomeDependency>();
        mock.Setup(_ => _.dbCall()).ReturnsAsync(expected);

        Something.Factory = () => return mock.Object; //<-- replace factory delegate

        var postParam = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
        postParam.Add("param", "value");

        var request = new DefaultHttpRequest(new DefaultHttpContext()){
            Query = new QueryCollection(postParam)
        };

        //Act
        var response = (OkObjectResult)await Something.Run(request, logger);
        string actual = (String) response.Value;

        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

The actual implementation will use the function when invoked, but with the factory method can be replaced when unit testing the function in isolation.